# The correct header file to access the cvLoadImage() function

Tags: opencv

I'm trying to get the algorithm provided in [this](https://github.com/sturkmen72/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection/blob/master/c4-pedestrian-detector.cpp#L1146) repository to work on windows. After countless issues, I'm only left with one unrecognized function cvLoadImage which is apprently depricated. I was instructed to work with the c++ API instead but the problem is that I will have to rewrite other parts of the code as well and I might end up breaking it.

```
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs_c.h>
```

returned the below error on Visual Studio:

"This header with legacy C API declarations has been removed from OpenCV. Legacy contants are available from legacy/constants_c.h file."

I imported all files provided in the opencv folder named constants_c.h, but none contained the function definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, that is the old OpenCV C API. You will need to port the old C functions to the c++ OpenCV API, e.g.:

- `cvNamedWindow` -> [`cv::namedWindow`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow)
- `cvRectangle` -> [`cv::rectangle`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9)
- `cvPoint` -> [`cv::Point`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/d84/group__core__basic.html#ga1e83eafb2d26b3c93f09e8338bcab192)

etc.

The code you're using is actually a mix of the old C API and the newer c++ API.
It's just a matter of going through all the C API calls in that repo and manually port them to the c++ API. As you can see above, most of the time that is fairly intuitive. When in doubt search the OpenCV documentation.

Additionally you should look into [YOLOv2](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolov2/) for Pedestrian detection.

**Update**:

There are multiple forks of this repository and it looks like [Berak](https://berak.github.io/smallfry/pose.html) already has already [removed the C API calls](https://github.com/berak/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection/commit/24a2ea81f3e41250ca3d68d79f4868d1b3b42685). His changes were [merged](https://github.com/sturkmen72/C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection/commits/master), so you should to pull the latest changes and rebuild:

```
cd C4-Real-time-pedestrian-detection
git pull
cmake . -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-std=c++11"
make -j8
```

I've tested the above on my machine:

[image: Charlie Chaplin movie with Pedestrian Detection green bounding boxes]

Regarding my setup, I ran into this error first:

```
cvdef.h:656:4: error: "OpenCV 4.x+ requires enabled C++11 support"
```

which is why I've passed the `-std=c++11` compiler flag to cmake.
This may be because I'm an older version of OSX (10.11.6) with Xcode 7.0 (about 3 years old now). The current machine has 8 cores, hence `make -j8`.
Feel free to change these two options as necessary on your machine.

Comment: It's not as simple as changing cvFucntion to cv::Function, the problem is the return types of each call. Going about the documentation for each one of these functions and figuring the needed changes otherwise is a tedious chore to say the least. All I want is the right header for the cvLoadImage to work. Is that still possible in opencv 4.0.0?

Comment: @JoeRaid sorry, missed your comment. instead of cvLoadImage you should use [`cv::imread`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html): it will a `cv::Mat` instead of the old `*IplImage`, so the following calls may need to be adjusted as well to use `cv::Mat` too if they aren't already

Comment: Yes, I picked up the new code (what a coincidence) and got it to work. Thanks for your time.